# Send a Crossdomain GET request Server Side with Phantomjs/Jquery

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, phantomjs

Is there a way to incorporate

```
$.get("http://localhost/?action=post", { site: "Test" } );
```

On the server side with PhantomJs and Jquery?

includeJs() and injectJs() don't seem to do anything but throw errors.

Also:

I have tried using regular Javscript on the server side, too:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var page = "http://localhost";
var params = "action=post&site=ipsum";
xhr.open("GET",page+"?"+params, false); 
xhr.send();
```

No luck that way either:

```
    xhr.open("GET",page+"?"+params, false);
```

Notice how I have the third parameter, async, set to "false"--- nothing happens when set to "true"!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google shows me they support cross domain request with the command line `--web-security=false` found here https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference

Comment: how would that translate into a phantomjs setting?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  I just told you the phantomjs setting to make it work.  Could you rephrase the question, maybe I'm just dense.

Comment: maybe I'm the one who's dense:) Thanks for pointing me towards this setting. Will try here and report results.

Comment: No dice... I might be lacking knowledge of the fundamentals of crossdomain requests-This may be a part of the solution, however.

Comment: cross domain requests are the exact same thing as a request to your same domain, it's just the browser that limits the request due to security constraints

Comment: And now I'm working with a browser on the server side...aye aye aye.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment to DMoses's answer, so I share my opinion as an answer here.

To translate web security setting mentioned by DMoses, you can use `phantomjs --web-security=no yourjsfile.js`.

Notice, this syntax works under macOS, but not viable within Ubuntu 16.04; with web security disabled in phantomjs execution, ubuntu still gives out 'CORS not supported' error. I am wondering if the option `--web-security=no` is not working under Ubuntu.

Comment: If somebody know how to fix 'Cross Origin Requests are not supported' error under Ubuntu, please comment here! Thank you very much.